# Implementing Webhooks for a custom service provider

Tags: c#, webhooks, asp.net-webhooks

Hi i'm currently required to create webhooks to listen for any updates that Synapse Pay send to me. In a nutshell im gathering users information to prepare and submit. Once i submit the users information i need to listen to check when the user is verified by Synapse Pay.

Firstly i know that i need to Subscribe(POST) to be able to recieve the webhook based on this information post.

```
    {
"scope": [
"USERS|POST",
"USER|PATCH",
"NODES|POST",
"NODE|PATCH",
"TRANS|POST",
"TRAN|PATCH"
],
"url": "http://requestb.in/11uvkob1"
}
```

Is the url that i use in the POST the address to my server webhook address?

The app that im posting the information is from a Mobile App using xamarin and need to listen from the mobile app so i might need to do some realtime from the server to the app to listen out for the verification im not sure.

I've seen many examples of using webhooks for Dropbox, Slack, Azure, Github etc. from a Github Library. But Synapse Pay (I think) will require some form of custom solution which i have no clue where to start with that.

- So I'm assuming that i create a webhook service
- Provide the url for the website in the subscription post
- Synapse Pay pings the url that i've created
- I update my database on the server side
- Push the information to the mobile app

Is this the correct flow?

If so can someone please direct me on how i would create the webhook and be listening for any events that happen from Synapse.

Thanks

Comment: I just looked at syapsepay documentation, exactly which flow you are trying to implement? Ideally you should implement a [Custom Receiver](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom).But I was not able to understand which syapse flow you are trying to implement

Comment: so once i send users information to Synapse pay to get verified, some information may not be verified instantly for instance the photo government ID. so i was told to listen for a webhook which will then give me asyncronous feature which will then allow me to detect when the photo id is verified

Comment: This is what Synapse Pay has told me todo..  Document verification is asynchronous, so the initial response may not always be valid (sometimes it will just be SUBMITTED or SUBMITTED|REVIEWING). Because of this, we recommend using subscriptions to stay updated with the latest statuses of your documents and users (as well as nodes and transactions). If you haven't done so already, here's more information on how that works: https://docs.synapsepay.com/docs/subscriptions

Comment: i figured that i would be using the Custom Reciever but now sure how to implement it and also how to i determine what information is recieved be to either saved to the database as a flag (Verified) or just push it as a push notification to the mobile